# How to implement a popup/banner in the mobile app that displays a warning if the installed version of the app is outdated?

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I am facing a jira ticket that introduces a banner (or a popup, doesn't matter) that displays a warning message if the installed version is outdated.

We keep the app's version in the config file locally. I thought that comparing it to the one in the store would do the job.

I have done a research and found possible solutions:

- For iOS, there is a handy api [https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?bundleId=${bundleId}](https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?bundleId=$%7BbundleId%7D). It does the job and pretty reliable
- For Android, the only option I know so far is to **scrape** the app's web page in the Play Market and extract the current version. This one is not very reliable.

So, I was wondering, what other options do I have?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use play store's in app updates https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-updates

Comment: What if I need a custom one?

Comment: You can still use this API to check if there is an update and implement your custom dialog with the response.